# How to convert frames between keyfames into keyframes?

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

[image]

**goal:**

I would like to know, how to convert a certain number of frames between two keyframes into keyframes, for each segment made out of two adjacent keyframes. 
In short, how to increase the keyframe resolution ?

**for what purpose ? :**

I want to animate a movement of a cube along a random path. It should not move smoothly but jump from one position to the next, just like quantuum leaps or the kind of movement you see when someone is moving through a dark room with a stroboskopic lamp flickering with 2 hz. 
In order to achieve this effect, I want at first make a standard smooth movement of a cube for about 5 seconds and only four keyframes, than I want to increase the number of keyframes automatically by converting some frames into keyframes, after this I would have enough keyframes and would change the interpolation mode in the gradph editor to constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make sure object is selected
- Hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>
- Type *Bake Action*
- Set first and last frame and frame_step
- Hit <kbd>Ok</kbd>
- Enjoy

Comment: perfect, what is the meaning of "bake" in this context ?

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred the meaning is to produce data from some source, like cake from a dough. In animation the data are keyframes and the source is the animation.